# How to separate thousands with commas using Facet Grid in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet

I have the following code:

```
    d = sns.FacetGrid(data = df,
                      col = 'Company',
                      sharex = False,
                      sharey = False,
                      col_wrap = 4)
    d.map(sns.distplot, 'Volume', kde = False, rug = True, fit = stats.norm)
    d.set_xlabels('volume')
    d.set_xticklabels(rotation = 45)
    plt.savefig(myDataRepository + 'figure_02__' + str(time_stamp) + '.png')
    ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(
         matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
```

The last two lines attempt to separate the x-axis values with commas.  For example, '500,000' instead of '500000'.

I see an error message saying:

```
"global name ax is not defined"
```

How would I amend `ax.` such that I can format the x-axis values with comma separation?

Thanks in advance!

**---EDIT BELOW---**

Here is updated code that I'm posting.  It still fails, but this time with error message `@property` when evaluating

```
d.ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(tkr.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
```

Revised Code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

d = sns.FacetGrid(data = df,
                  col = 'Company',
                  sharex = False,
                  sharey = False,
                  col_wrap = 4)
d.map(sns.distplot, 'Volume', kde = False, rug = True, fit = stats.norm)
d.set_xlabels('volume')
d.set_xticklabels(rotation = 45)
plt.savefig(myDataRepository + 'figure_02__' + str(time_stamp) + '.png')

d.ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(tkr.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
```

`@cphlewis` is suggesting that I put the ax.get_axis() inside the Facet Grid.  But how???

Putting `ax.get_axis()` inside the FacetGrid does not seem to solve this problem (assuming I did so correctly).  Is it even *possible* to use this `ax.get_axis()` function with the Seaborn FacetGrid?

The error message:

```
    971             return self.axes[0, 0]
    972         else:
--> 973             raise AttributeError
    974 
    975     @property

AttributeError:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this problem too and came up with a clean solution here by adding a simple loop to format all of the axes with the comma.

```
# set up the standard plotting of the df
g = sns.PairGrid(wmix, vars = ['ambulatory', 'wheelchair', 'stretcher'], hue="holiday")

g.map_upper(plt.scatter)
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, lw=2, legend=False)
g.add_legend()


# now add the comma and remove decimal formats for each y axis
for ax in g.axes[:,0]:
  ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))

# this adds the axis labels to each plot
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
g.fig.suptitle('Ride Count Relationships');
```

Comment: I've been looking for this. There didnt seem to be an obvious `pyplot` substitute for this so I couldn't seem to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `ax` inside the `FacetGrid`:

```
df = random((5, 5))
d = sns.FacetGrid(data=df)
dir(d.ax.get_xaxis())
```

and aha, `get_major_formatter` is in that list.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!  I amended the code as follows: `dir(d.ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(
         matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ','))))` and I'm seeing an "@property" error message.  Is that the correct way to modify the code?  Thanks.

Comment: ( Get your custom formatter working in a really simple dummy plot. Then work on applying it in the right place in seaborn.)

Comment: The `p` is part of the lambda function.  I'm still not understanding how to incorporate your suggestion into my code...

Comment: `p` is not used in the lambda function. This makes me suspect you haven't gotten your custom formatter working anywhere.

Comment: That's correct.  The custom formatter is not working.  I don't know how to incorporate your suggestion into my code.  I'm not familiar with `dir`.  Are you able to shed some light?

Comment: Don't ask two questions in one question, or shift from one problem to the next: you started with finding where to *apply* the custom formatter, now you're asking how to *design* one.